# Include CSS files in tsc TypeScript compilation

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, tsc, tsconfig

I am trying to create a React TypeScript NPM package. I have finished my code and created `package.json` and `tsconfig.json`. But inside my package I also have a bunch of CSS files that I want to include in my package. This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "es5",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  "files": [
    "src/index.tsx"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My problem is that when I run `tsc` in my folder, it creates all `.js` files and all `.d.ts` files in `/dist`, but I see no CSS files at all. How do I do to make it include CSS?

Answer (score 14):

So this is exactly the question I was looking for. Unfortunately for us both I found our answer in this post https://vccolombo.github.io/blog/tsc-how-to-copy-non-typescript-files-when-building/

Basically what it said was that tsc does not do anything other than turn TS code into JS code and there are no plans to change this in the future.

Comment: TL;DR: After the build, copy the files to the build directly using custom commands or the copyfiles package.

Comment: Basically just install rimraf and copyfiles. Make sure to add `"rootDir": "src"` and `"outDir": "dist"` to your tsconfig. Then add `"scripts": { "clean": "rimraf dist/", "copy": "copyfiles -u 1 src/**/*.html src/**/*.css dist/", "build": "npm run clean && tsc && npm run copy", }` these to your package.json. Running `npm run build` will build the typescript into the dist directory and copy html and css files to your dist directory in the same structure as the src directory. It works perfectly fine. Just make sure to add any other extensions to that copy command like `src/**/*.ttf` in my case.

Answer (score -4):

Add this to your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }]
  }
}
```

More information can be gotten here https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-plugin-css-modules.

Comment: This is getting downvotes because that package offers IDE support, but not packaging support.  This question is about packaging support.